# SQL Server 2005 SP2 or SP3 not updating Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

I applied SQL Server 2005 SP2 and marked all the components to be updated, including Client tools, but the version in the Help -> About box still has version 1399, while the server does indeed had 3042.

I then re-applied SP2 to only Client tools, and everything ran successfully (again, first time did too) but still, no version update for management studio.

Now, I just applied SP3 with everything successfully, but still management studio version did not get updated.

How can I update it? Or at least how can I uninstall just Management studio so I can install it from a newer DVD?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same problem. I upgraded the server to SP3 but version is still shown for RTM. Please suggest as to why the version upgrade is not shown there. Regards
Vipin Goel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but I had to manually un-install Client Tools, re-install them using SQL Server 2005 setup, and THEN apply the updates.

It wasn't working by just trying to apply updates over the existing original installation.

And i mention un-installing using the SQL Server 2005 Setup because trying to do it from the Add/Remove Programs dialog won't let you or will give you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Control Panel > Add Remove programs and then choose the appropriate SQL Server installation, this will start the typical install wizard for SQL Server.

You can then select the specific components that you wish to uninstall.

If you are having difficulties with SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 may I suggest that you visit the SQL Server Central forums as there are a wealth of resources for SQL Server SP3. It was actually due to user demand from this forum that resulted in there even being an SP3 release.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Forum146-1.aspx

Let me know how you get on.

Cheers, John

Comment: Well, the original question is not answered, it's not about SP3, it's about how to update management studio.

Comment: @gerleim: Sounds like you may have misunderstood the question. A successful install of SP3 will update SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). The reply details both how to uninstall a specific version of SSMS and then how to subsequently troubleshoot issues with installing SP3.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Error in sql server sp3 installation log which caused this:
Error Number              : 29538
Error Description         : MSP Error: 29538  SQL Server Setup did not have the administrator permissions required to rename a file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\mssqlsystemresource1.ldf. To continue, verify that the file exists, and either grant administrator permissions to the account currently running Setup or log in with an administrator account. Then run SQL Server Setup again.